# Segmentation fault occurs way after index leaves array boundary in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, debugging, segmentation-fault

I have this code:

```
#include <cstdio>

int foo[100];

int main()
{
for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
    foo[i]=10000;
}
```

Debugging with GDB gives a surprising result:

```
[New Thread 23684.0x59b4]
[New Thread 23684.0x5c0c]
[New Thread 23684.0x541c]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000401564 in main () at C:\Users\DARREN\Documents\Visual Studio 
2017\Projects\Untitled1.cpp:9
warning: Source file is more recent than executable.
9       }
(gdb) print i
$1 = 4080
(gdb)
```

Now, I know the statement `foo[i]=10000` caused the error, but I declared foo to be only of size `100`. Why would the value of `i` be so big before the error occurs?

Any explanation is appreciated.

Comment: Accessing an element out of bounds is "undefined behavior" which means that anything can happen. "Not reporting any problems until long after the error occurred" is one possible outcome of "anything".

Comment: Unfortunately, undefined behavior doesn't have to result in an obvious problem. Since `que[]` is part of the data segment it seems that there was a lot of valid memory locations that could be read before hitting an invalid one.

Comment: C++ operates on an "Only pay for what you use" philosophy. A correct program has no buffer overruns, so checking for buffer overruns is a penalty they should not have to pay. As a result there is zero checking, and the program will keep on going until something, possibly resulting from the overrun, brings it to a halt.

Comment: Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of plain arrays and use [`.at(size_t pos)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) instead of the subscript operator.  This way you will get an exception when going over the boundaries.

Comment: This is UB. If you want bounds checking, use `std::array<10001,val> que`, and use `que.at(i)` instead of `que[i]`.

Comment: @Baaing Cow  It looks like there are used pages of memory of 16K.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate as the linked answer doesn't answer the question, which is why is there not an error until offset 4080.   Just saying "that's undefined behaviour" is not answering the question, any more than "Q:Why is the sky blue? A:Because it isn't yellow"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you made an update to your question you posted this:

> ```
> int foo[100];
>
> int main()
> {
> for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
>     foo[i]=10000;
> }
> ```

And you are asking about segmentation fault.

Here you have an array with a size of `100` and you have a loop that ranges `[0,9999]` and within the for loop you are indexing the array with the for loops incremental variable `i`. When you step through the for loop for each iteration of `i` and you get to:

```
foo[i] = 10000;
```

when `i <= 99` everything is okay.

What do you suppose happens when `i >= 100`?

When you use raw arrays there is no bounds checking; and this is something that you and the user will have to be responsible for. If you want automatic bounds checking done for you to prevent this out of bounds memory segmentation fault you should use any of the standard containers such as `std::vector<T>`, `std::list<T>`, `std::set<T>` etc. depending on your needs. If you need to use array index notation then `std::vector<T>` is the way to go. Or any other `vector` from any other library such as `boost`.

**EDIT**

For you to fix this problem you would have to either increase the size of the array from `100` to `10,000` or you would have to decrease your loop's condition from `i<10000` to `i<100` to accommodate for proper array indexing. Do not forget that `C++` arrays have their starting index at `0` so you would have a basic array and loop as such:

```
int var[10]; // Uninitialized

for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i ) {
    var[i] = 0; // Initialize all array indexes to 0
}
```

Notice that the condition in the for loop is `i < 10` which is less than the actual size of the array when it is declared and not `i <= 10` less than or equal to for this would also generate a segmentation fault or out of bounds error.

Comment: OP seems to be asking why the error happens at i=4080 rather than i=100, not why an error happens at all.

Comment: @MilesBudnek Maybe, but the first should be obvious before the later and anyone who isn't sure about out of bound errors shouldn't be accessing array indexes that are greater than the indexed array's size. However if he is concerned with `i = 4080` then he needs to consider that let's say it is a 32bit system then an `int` type should be 4 bytes. Well `4 x 4080 = 16320 bytes` and what is the normal page or sector size on a 32bit system?

Comment: @MilesBudnek So when you end up getting this far towards the end of a page file; and you start to experience cache misses and other things; they can also lead to seg faults. Basically he is trampling on memory that doesn't belong to that array as it is not or it wasn't reserved for it initially.